# Plotting minimum value array for multiple lines with different sized arrays

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

For my thesis I had to do several tests where I measured a certain force over a distance. This gave me two arrays per test. One is the displacement (X values) and the other is the force (y value).

I have imported that data in python with pandas and with the code beneath I got a curved fit. The thing I want to do now is to find the lowest and maximum values for every part of the graph. Since the calculated x_lines and y_lines are of different sizes I can't find a way to do this. Could anyone help me with writing the right code to easily perform this task? For some reason, I cannot add the pictures that I have plotted, but they are 4 lines that intersect multiple times, I want to have two lines (including its x and y values for later calculations) that represent the maximum and minimum y value for every x.

```py
def objective_4(x,a,b,c,d,e):
    return a * x**4 +b*x**3 +c*x**2+d*x+e


for i in range(8,12):  
    pars, cov = curve_fit(objective_4, df.iloc[:,i][1:DATA_END_VALUES[i]],df.iloc[:,i+16][1:DATA_END_VALUES[i]])
    x_line = arange(min(df.iloc[:,i][1:DATA_END_VALUES[i]]), max(df.iloc[:,i][1:DATA_END_VALUES[i]]), 1)
    a, b, c, d, e = pars
    y_line = objective_4(x_line, a, b, c, d, e)

    if i==8:
        y_line31=y_line
        x_line31=x_line
    if i==9:
        y_line32=y_line
        x_line32=x_line
    if i==10:
        y_line33=y_line
        x_line33=x_line
    if i==11:
        y_line34=y_line
        x_line34=x_line

    ymin3=np.empty(1182)

plt.plot(x_line31,y_line31)
plt.plot(x_line32,y_line32)
plt.plot(x_line33,y_line33)
plt.plot(x_line34,y_line34)
plt.ylim(bottom=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `NameError: name 'curve_fit' is not defined` This question needs a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always provide a complete [mre] with **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output**, as **[formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, only plot images are okay. If you don't include an mre, it is likely the question will be downvoted, closed, and deleted.

Comment: You can try 1D interpolation of each of your data arrays (for example `scipy.interpolate.interp1d`). Then you can write a function that finds the minimum/maximum of the interpolation functions using a new, x-array that covers all data x-arrays.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney, I'm sorry but I'm new to python so It is very hard for me to do that. I am working on it right now but it could take a while. I used "from scipy.optimize import curve_fit" for the curve fit to work. boxhot, It is very hard to do that since some of my x values are in range of -70 to 0 while others are in the range of -300 to 0.

Comment: edit existing questions, don't open new ones.